# What causes plants in the prunus genus to reach anthesis?

Tags: botany, temperature, fruit, environment, flowers

In a related question, I ask how to [trick fruit trees into flowering later in the spring by prolonging frozen ground conditions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/69186/trick-fruit-trees-into-flowering-later-prolong-frozen-ground-conditions).

However, I'm starting to realize that I don't actually understand what triggers plants to flower in the spring in the first place. Possibilities include:

- [Photoperiodism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoperiodism)
- Air temperature
- Soil/root temperature

---

It seems to me that this is a simple enough question. I'm guessing that plants in a certain genus would have a fairly specific genetic program that would stipulate when they should flower.
For example:

`If root temperature is greater than X (for greater than Y duration), and daylength is greater than Z, then initiate flowering.`

I'm **not** looking for the specific values (example `x` = `10 degrees C`); the values would likely vary by species or even by plant. I'm just wondering what the **primary variables** are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer provided by the **University of Guelph Plant Sciences Department** (they specialize in Malus):

> Flowering of Malus and Prunus is driven primarily by air temperature. Provided sufficient winter chilling has accumulated for a given cultivar, tree growth and bud development will advance when air temps are above approx. 5 degrees Celsius. This process is irreversible. Once enough heat units (degree days) are accumulated, the flowers will open.
>
> Flowering is a complex physiological process within the plant, driven by temperature. Photo-period likely does not play a large role in Malus.

Answer (score 4):

Here’s how it works. Every morning when the sun breaks over the horizon — no matter what time of year it is — a clock starts ticking inside the trees. After a specific number of hours, the plants’ cells start producing high levels of a molecule known as the FT protein. This protein is responsible for initiating processes that help the plant grow.

But the FT protein has a curious property: In the absence of sunlight, it curls up and dies. So when the sun sets, it degrades rather quickly and becomes useless to the plant.

Nilsson thinks this peculiarity is the key to the seasonality of certain flowering plants, including most trees that blossom in the spring.

If a plant is genetically programmed to produce lots of FT protein starting, say, 13 hours after dawn, the molecule will be abundant during the last few hours of daylight in the longer days of summer. And those few hours are enough to kick-start crucial growth processes. So the cherry trees do most of the heavy lifting for the spring festival — bud and flower formation — way back in the summer and early fall.

As autumn progresses and the days shorten, that same 13-hour clock — the number of hours will vary by species and even by individual plant — means that the FT protein will be produced in darkness, and it will degrade before it can work its magic. The trees take this as a signal to drop their leaves and stop generating new buds.

When winter arrives, day length and temperatures both reach their annual nadir. At this point, the plant goes through vernalization, a dormancy period that has enormous importance in protecting the trees, for reasons explained below.

In springtime, one might imagine that the FT protein process would reverse: The days get longer, the FT protein is produced during daylight hours, and the plant kicks off its growth process. Surprisingly, that’s not what happens.

While the cherry trees recognize the arrival of winter by sensing a decline in daylight, they detect the arrival of spring based on temperature. They wait for what’s called a “temperature sum”— basically a bunch of warm days in a row. (The precise temperatures and durations required vary by plant.) When the temperature sum is reached, the blossoms open. Of course, since the National Park Service can’t control the weather, peak blossoming doesn’t always coincide with the Cherry Blossom Festival’s lighting of the stone lantern and the Japanese taiko drummers.

The cherry trees’ habit of marking the start of winter by daylight and the end of winter by temperature is reversed in some other plants. Plant biologists, for example, base much of their genetic research on Arabidopsis thaliana, or mouse-ear cress, a small plant that belongs to the same family as cabbage. (“It’s the laboratory rat of the plant world,” says Nilsson, because its small genome enables researchers to closely observe its genetically based behaviors. ) The plant measures the arrival of winter by a drop in temperatures and decides when to flower in spring by day length.

Click [here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national/what-makes-the-cherry-trees-bloom-when-they-do/2011/03/29/AFvRbRfC_story.html?utm_term=.103ab95e7ee2) for the source of this information, hope this helps :)

-Sartoaster

Comment: In continental countries winters can be very bright with latent fosts that kill flowers. FT is probably accelerated with high temps.

Answer (score 0):

The **University of Saskatchewan Plant Sciences Department** builds on Guelph's answer:

> In this context, my answer would be that photo-period definitely does
>   not play a large role in Malus and Prunus.
>
> Plants in these genera need
>   their chilling requirement satisfied followed by temperatures high
>   enough to allow growth to occur. Within reasonable limits, the higher
>   the temperature, the sooner to bloom.
>
> I have seen apple and plum trees
>   that were neglected in a cooler room at 5 degrees Celsius form October
>   to April reach anthesis with only enough intermittent/inconsistent
>   light to produce barely a trace of anthocyanin and chlorophyll
>   pigments.

Answer (score 0):

From The Principles of Fruit-Growing By L. H. Bailey (The Rural Science Series):

[image]